# Difference between methods of determining debug or release in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I am aware of two methods of determining whether my app is in running in debug mode:

`const bool.fromEnvironment("dart.vm.product")` returns true if release.

And this from the Sentry part of the Flutter docs:

```
bool get isInDebugMode {
  // Assume we're in production mode
  bool inDebugMode = false;

  // Assert expressions are only evaluated during development. They are ignored
  // in production. Therefore, this code will only turn `inDebugMode` to true
  // in our development environments!
  assert(inDebugMode = true);

  return inDebugMode;
}
```

Are those two always equivalent or are there situations where they would give different answers? Which should I use? The first method being compile time seems to favour it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general they should be the same, but there can be differences.

`const bool.fromEnvironment("dart.vm.product")` depends on release build being performed. I haven't checked if `profile` build returns `true` or `false`

`assert(inDebugMode = true);` depends on asserts being enabled.
asserts are enabled in debug mode by default and disabled in release builds by default but there should be a way to enable/disable asserts independently of release/debug mode, but I haven't found how. Perhaps it's not exposed in Flutter or it is not implemented in Dart yet.

I'd think `bool.fromEnvironment()` works better with tree-shaking because it can be used to create a const value.

Comment: `flutter test -h` also doesn't expose any information and `flutter test --enable-asserts` tells me that the option is not recognized.

Comment: I thought so that it actually is already implemented but not yet exposed by the `flutter` tool.

Comment: That's useful. Any guidance on which is preferred?

Comment: I'd think `bool.fromEnvironment()` works better with tree-shaking because it can be used to create a const value.